# android measuring angle

Tags: android, android-sensors

I know a good amount of java but this is my first time programming with the android sdk. I need to get the rotation of the phone in real time and display it on the screen. I was wondering what sensor method to use, as I heard that getOrientation was processor intensive and may not work in real time. Secondly, I was wondering which class I'd right this program in, I don't quite understand android class hierarchy yet. Thirdly, how would I make the numbers change on the screen in real time? 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering what sensor method to use, as I heard that getOrientation was processor intensive and may not work in real time.

You'll want to have a look at the [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) object.

> Secondly, I was wondering which class I'd right this program in, I don't quite understand android class hierarchy yet.

To get you started, you could build all this code into an `Activity`.  Unlike a traditional Java program there is no `main()` entry point method and you won't user the constructors of application component classes to instantiate them.  Lifecycle callback methods like `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` are where you will want to do initialization and teardown of instance information.  [This guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) may help you in how to construct your application to use a single `Activity`.

> Thirdly, how would I make the numbers change on the screen in real time? Thanks for the help!

The `OrientationEventListener` includes a callback method for each change, simply use this callback to update a view in your UI.

Here is a simple example pulling it all together:

```
public class OrientationActivity extends Activity {
    private OrientationEventListener mListener;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mTextView = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(mTextView);

        mListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
              mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(orientation);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mListener.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mListener.disable();
    }
}
```